# Issue with displaying results in the loop after collect()

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

### What is the problem about?

I have a problem displaying data that has been read from a text file. The file (yields.txt) has 3 lines and it looks like a fourth line is being read as well, with some strange content.

### File

File encoding: UTF-8 -> I also check for ASCII but same issue
EOL: Unix(LF) -> I also check for Windows (CRLF) but same issue
[image]

```
1 -0.0873962663951055 0.0194176287820278 -0.0097985244947938 -0.0457230361016478 -0.0912513154921251 0.0448220622524235
2 0.049279031957286 0.069222988721009 0.0428232461362216 0.0720027150750844 -0.0209348305073702 -0.0641023433269808
3 0.0770763924363555 -0.0790020383071036 -0.0601622344182963 -0.0207625817307966 -0.0193570710130222 -0.0959349375686872
```

### Bug Description

Log from console

> in mapper
> return Row(ID=int(fields[0]),asset_1 = float(fields[1]), asset_2 = float(fields[2]), asset_3 = float(fields[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lUaNP.png)),asset_4 = float(fields[4]), asset_5 = float(fields[5]), asset_6 = float(fields[6]))
> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: b'PK\x03\x04\x14\x00\x00\x00\x08\x00AW\xef\xbf\xbdT\xef\xbf\xbdu\xef\xbf\xbdDZ\xef\xbf\xbd\x1e\x03i\x18\xef\xbf\xbd\x07'

I have also tried to find out what is within this content
[image: Trying to decode it]

and it is some strange data that does not appear in the text file at all which I checked with the script shown below:

```
import os

DATA_FOLDER_PATHNAME = 
'\\'.join(os.path.dirname(__file__).split('\\') 
[:-1])+'\\'+'data'+'\\'+'yields.txt'

with open(DATA_FOLDER_PATHNAME, 'r', encoding='ansi') as f:
    print(f.read())
```

You can see that an empty line is visible but I do not know how to improve my code to avoid this bug.
[image: empty line]

### Code

```
import findspark
import os
findspark.init(PATH_TO_SPARK)

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import Row

DATA_FOLDER_PATHNAME = '\\'.join(os.path.dirname(__file__).split('\\')[:-1])+'\\'+'data' # location of data file

def mapper(line):
    fields = line.split()
    return Row(ID=int(fields[0]),asset_1 = float(fields[1]), asset_2 = float(fields[2]), asset_3 = float(fields[3]),asset_4 = float(fields[4]), asset_5 = float(fields[5]), asset_6 = float(fields[6]))

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("SparkSQL").getOrCreate()
lines = spark.sparkContext.textFile(DATA_FOLDER_PATHNAME, minPartitions = 2000, use_unicode = False) 
assets_with_yields_rdd = lines.map(mapper)
assets_with_yields_df = spark.createDataFrame(assets_with_yields_rdd).cache()
assets_with_yields_df.createOrReplaceTempView('assets_with_yields_view')

assets_with_yields_view_df = spark.sql('select * from assets_with_yields_view')

print(80*'-')
for asset in assets_with_yields_view_df.collect():
    print(asset)
print(80*'-')
spark.stop()
```

### Question

Does anyone know what could cause such a weird issue?

Comment: Can you provide a data sample? My recommendation is to first read the data using a simpler framework like pandas or even just parsing the file "manually" to see what the root cause is. Also check the .txt file encoding. Also I recommend reading data using .read function and specifying .options() as needed. Here [link](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources-load-save-functions.html) to documentation. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this was that I had several files in one folder and it read them all in turn, so there were some discrepancies.